# How to specify a location for TypeScript in tasks.json?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

If you ask for a TypeScript build task in Visual Studio code, you get something like this:

```
    {
        "type": "typescript",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$tsc"
        ],
        "group": "build"
    }
```

This causes it run "tsc" on the command line. How can I change the path of "tsc" so that it runs something like "./node_modules/.bin/tsc".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS code has number of predefined [problem matches](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_processing-task-output-with-problem-matchers) included.

If I understand u correctly, I think what you're looking for is [creating your own problem matcher](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher).

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified the question. Original phrasing involved a misunderstanding of how it worked.